# Why I can't make my views in the center of the table view container

Tags: ios, layout

I always write the layout in the code, and now I am trying to switch to using the Interface Builder to achieve this.I have simple tableviewcell like this.

[image]

All the three items, imageView, nameLabel and introLabel and all in the center of the the parent view. I added the constraints as below, but it does not work and all the three items are based on the right of the screen. Can somebody help me how to add constraint for my case?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to centre all the elements horizontally w.r.t parent then select all elements and apply constraint as per attached screen shot.[image]